# Images not showing on NetlifyCMS and GatsbyJS

Tags: gatsby, netlify, netlify-cms, gatsby-image

I can't get images to work on my blog which is using NetlifyCMS and GatsbyJS I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my config for NetlifyCMS

```
 backend:
      name: git-gateway
      branch: master
    publish_mode: editorial_workflow
   media_folder: '../common/src/assets/images/uploads'
   #public_folder: '../common/src/assets/images/uploads'
```

Collections articles

```
folder: 'packages/common/src/articles'
```

Gasbyjs Config for the CMS

```
{
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `articles`,
        path: `../common/src/articles`
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `../common/src/assets/images/uploads`
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `common-images`,
        path: `../common/src/assets/images/uploads`
      }
    },
```

My gatsby's config for files

```
{
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `common`,
        path: `../common/src/assets/`
      }
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-json`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `data`,
        path: `../common/src/data/`
      }
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
        short_name: `starter`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#663399`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `../common/src/assets/images/favicon.png` // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      }
    },
```

and my project folder
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `config.yml` paths from:

```
 backend:
   name: git-gateway
   branch: master
   publish_mode: editorial_workflow
   media_folder: '../common/src/assets/images/uploads'
   #public_folder: '../common/src/assets/images/uploads'
```

To something similar to:

```
   name: git-gateway
   branch: master
   publish_mode: editorial_workflow
   media_folder: 'static/assets/images/uploads'
   public_folder: '/assets/images/uploads'
```

*Note: I would hardly avoid relative paths in these media configurations. Of course, adapt it to your needs but keep the `/static` folder present for the `media_folder` and the slash (`/`) at the beginning of `public_folder`.*

You will need to use the [static folder](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/images-and-media/static-folder/) approach since it's the only way to make external images be accessible from `/public` folder requests, as you can see in the [guide provided by Netlify](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/gatsby/#add-netlify-cms-to-your-site):

```
media_folder: static/img
public_folder: /img
```

Comment: I thought the public folder should have the static I don't have a static folder in common?

Comment: All the images in common/assets/images/portfolio are generated to http://localhost:8000/static/

Comment: `static` folder must be placed in the root of the project. The public folder is generated once the code is compiled

Comment: The project is set up a bit different

Comment: Either way, you need to notify Netlify where those assets are, so the static folder must be present in the configuration

Comment: Yes but I did that, all my images are in the project are at 
packages/common/src/assets/images

I upload all blog files to 
packages/common/src/assets/images/uploads

That is working but the images are not showing on the site

Comment: When you run gatsby build it supposed to then put them in 
packages/landing-gatsby/public/static

Comment: If the config.yml is set as I wrote and the images are being saved correctly in the public folder, what is missing if the relativity of the paths in the sources

Comment: What you wrote is not working and can't be right you wrote "  media_folder: 'static/common/src/assets/images/uploads'" the media folder is where files are stored in the repo in my project all files are at common/src/assets/images/uploads

Comment: It's quite simple. If you want to use images in Gatsby + Netlify you **must** change your media and public folders to what I wrote. Based and focus on the examples provided: https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/configuration-options/#media-and-public-folders This is because the approach needs to be through /static folder, otherwise, your code won't know where are the images and the paths will break. Adapt the paths I wrote to your needs, the important part is to use the /static folder.

Comment: Images work fine for all my site just not the blog, so Gatsby + Netlify are setups correctly its something to do with how  NetlifyCMS is setup

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229244/discussion-between-ferran-buireu-and-almog-koren).

Comment: For some reason it's trying to find images here after a publish a new post 
https://almog.io/blog/screen-shot-2021-02-26-at-11.47.32-am.png

and I have this public_folder: '/packages/landing-gatsby/public/static'

Maybe its needs to be public_folder: '/packages/landing-gatsby/public/static/images'